# Get File List from sub folder of Documents Directory swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, directory, document

I am using this code to get list of PDF files from documents directory.
Now I want to find list of PDF files from Folder named "MyFiles" in Document Directory if that folder exists.

How can I do this??

```
func listFilesFromDocumentsFolder() -> [String]
{
    var theError = NSErrorPointer()
    let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

    if dirs != nil {
        let dir = dirs![0]
        let fileList = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(dir, error: theError) as! [String]
        var count = fileList.count
        for var i = 0; i < count; i++
        {
            var filePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
            filePath = filePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileList[i])
            let properties = [NSURLLocalizedNameKey, NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLContentModificationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey]
            var attr = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath, error: NSErrorPointer())
        }
        return fileList.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }.map{ $0.lastPathComponent } as [String]
    }else{
        let fileList = [""]
        return fileList
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You are supposed to ask a question. Not to ask to someone code it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code..

```
func listFilesFromDocumentsFolder() -> [String]
{
    var theError = NSErrorPointer()
    let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

    if dirs != nil {
        let dir = dirs![0]//this path upto document directory

        //this will give you the path to MyFiles
        let MyFilesPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/BioData")
        if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(MyFilesPath) {
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(MyFilesPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: theError)
        } else {
            println("not creted or exist")
        }

        let fileList = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(MyFilesPath, error: theError) as! [String]

        var count = fileList.count
        for var i = 0; i < count; i++
        {
            var filePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
            filePath = filePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileList[i])
            let properties = [NSURLLocalizedNameKey, NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLContentModificationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey]
            var attr = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath, error: NSErrorPointer())
        }
        println("fileList: \(fileList)")
        return fileList.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }.map{ $0.lastPathComponent } as [String]
    }else{
        let fileList = [""]
        return fileList
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this may be possible by implementing an extension to NSFileManager that implements the SequenceType protocol. But you could easily convert your code to using a while loop:

```
// path to documents directory
let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
let myFilesPath = documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/MyFiles")
let files = filemanager.enumeratorAtPath(myFilesPath)
while let file = files?.nextObject() {
     println(file)
}
```

Comment: I want the fileList which are only in the "MyFiles" folder.

Comment: Underrated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code:

```
    func listFilesFromDocumentsFolder() -> [String]
    {
        var theError = NSErrorPointer()
        let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

        if dirs != nil {
            let dir = dirs![0]//this path upto document directory

            //this will give you the path to MyFiles
            let MyFilesPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/MyFiles")


            let fileList = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(MyFilesPath, error: theError) as! [String]
            var count = fileList.count
            for var i = 0; i < count; i++
            {
                var filePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
                filePath = filePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileList[i])
                let properties = [NSURLLocalizedNameKey, NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLContentModificationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey]
                var attr = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath, error: NSErrorPointer())
            }
            return fileList.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }.map{ $0.lastPathComponent } as [String]
        }else{
            let fileList = [""]
            return fileList
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to wrap `NSFileManager` calls in a do-try-catch syntax

Comment: Code above written will crash the app if that folder doesn't exists.

Comment: Yes, but at least that you can do by your self as Koren said by try-catch or by checking folder exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 4.2 - 5.0** using **Extension on FileManager** :

```
extension FileManager {

func urls(for DocumentsDirectory : String) -> [URL]? {
    let dirs = urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        //this will give you the path to MyFiles
    let MyFilesPath = dirs[0].appendingPathComponent("/" + DocumentsDirectory)

    let fileList = try? contentsOfDirectory(at: MyFilesPath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)       
    return fileList
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 3**

```
    let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let myFilesPath = documentDirectoryPath.appending("/Inbox")
    let files = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: myFilesPath)

    while let file = files?.nextObject() {
        print("\(myFilesPath)/\(file)")
    }
```